# Graph Theory Proofs on Paths

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Prove or disprove: If $G = (V, E)$ is an undirected graph where every vertex has degree at
least 4 and $u \in V$, then there are at least $64$ distinct paths in $G$ that start at $u$.

- I tried to generate some counterexamples, but of course it is quite hard to find 64 paths for each one. I noticed that $64 = 4^3$. Maybe this is related to making a choice between two paths at least 3 times?
- I have no other ideas. Any help?

Comment: $64$ is $4^3$, not $2^3$.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Sorry, fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's count the number of paths we know exist.  You can follow along on $K_5$, since that's the lower bound.

- There are **4** paths of length 1.
- For each of those, there are at least three paths of length 2, since each of those vertices has four neighbors but we can't go back to $u$.  So the graph has **12** paths of length 2.
- For each of those, there are at least two paths of length 3, again you can't return to the previous two vertices in the path.  So there are at least **24** paths of length 3.
- Third verse same as the first: each path of length 3 can be extended to at least one path of length 4, so there are **24** paths of length 4.

$4+12+24+24=64.$

This is, in fact, the total number of paths starting from a given vertex of $K_5$, so it is the best lower pound possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is true. For a counterexample, take $G = K_5$ and label the vertices $V = \{u, a, b, c, d\}$. Then there are $4!$ paths of length $5$ which start at $u$ (e.g.: $u \to a \to b \to c \to d$ and $u \to c \to b \to a \to d$). Counting up all such paths over all possible lengths, we have:
$$
4! + 3! + 2! + 1! + 0! = 34 < 64
$$